# Blender 2.8 Cycles - Render issue while render preview is good

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am new to 3d modelling.

In my scene I am getting a weird render behavior. The lamp is uv unwrapped and applied dark color texture. It looks good in render preview but when I render, it is completely irrelevant. I suspected denoising but turning it off didn't help.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: could you provide more details ? Including how it looks rendered without denoising, how many samples are used, maybe provide the .blend file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image that shows your settings for color management.

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate your answers very much. 

I have found the reason. In a seperate scene collection I had the duplicate of the object set unvisible....